# Usage of 64-bit native libraries is disabled, but App Bundle contains only 64-bit native libraries

Tags: android, android-studio

Usage of 64-bit native libraries is disabled, but App Bundle contains only 64-bit native libraries.

When uploading the aab file to the Google store, this error is prompted...How to resolve it ?

[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrdZl.png)    [sec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrUu6.png)